# making new request in dio by removing first request

Tags: flutter, http, dart, future, dio

I have a function which makes a api call, if i call that api twice, i want to cancel first call i'm trying to use dio for this

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';


final _dio = Dio();
CancelToken abc = CancelToken();
Future<void> makeSearchQuery(String searchTerm) async {
  abc.cancel();
  return _dio.get(searchTerm, cancelToken: abc).then((value) {
    print(value);
  }).catchError((e) {});
}

void main() async {
  await makeSearchQuery("https://reqres.in/api/products/3");
  await makeSearchQuery("https://reqres.in/api/products/3");
}
```

The problem is i'm not getting any response for either of that, though i should get the response for second call
P.S actually I'm calling this function in onPressed of a button if that matters.

Comment: don't want to cancel request after specific time i want to cancel it when i make new request

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a debouncer,

```
class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  Timer? _timer;

  Debouncer({
    this.milliseconds = 500,
  });

  void run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer?.cancel();
    }

    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}
```

use `run` method to call your function.

when timer gets canceled your function won't get called